# AngularJS multiple class="{{class1}} {{class2}}" automatic sorting by words?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class, ng-controller

I've got 2 Divs

```
<div ng-controller="controller1">
  <div ng-controller="controller2" class="{{changesindividually}}">
</div>
</div>
```

Inside controller1 there is

```
$scope.changesindividually = 'one column wide'
```

Inside controller2 there is

```
$scope.changesindividually = 'two column wide'
```

**The Problem:**
Changing the parent class this way, is possible, however:
After doing:

```
$scope.changesindividually = 'two column wide'
```

From the child controller, **{{changesindividually}} changes to 
'column wide two' instead of the supplied 'two column wide'.**
In my case this is problematic since this order of classes is required because of the css logic.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: You're going to want to rethink this approach altogether. Relying on specific class value strings for your application logic (or even for CSS alone) is just asking for frustration.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get plenty of good advice if you describe your greater goal in your question.

Comment: I understand. However in this scenario it's some really odd behavior of angular JS to sort the phrases instead of getting them in in the given order. I do not really understand why it is doing this. Even putting multiple classes as {{class1}} {class2}} will in worst case result in {{class2}} {{class1}}. That's a bit misleading, discussable a bug maybe even? When doing 'sixteen column', it'll end in column sixteen, when putting anything as the last char of column except n, it'll show it in the right order.

Comment: Are you checking values in your app (with a breakpoint) or are you just looking at the browser? It may not even be Angular making the change.

Comment: scope.$parent.$parent.middleColumnsClass = 'sixteen column'; and console.log(scope.$parent.$parent.middleColumnsClass), that's where it stays the same. I have some feeling the DOM engine is doing this, however where'd be the purpose of that when it's only happening for the classes that are defined within the css (as e.g. column,wide,sixteen)

Comment: There's nothing really odd about it. CSS class order isn't supposed to matter. They're probably not stored as a string anyway.

Comment: Well odd maybe to a point where it's hard to figure out where something is happening that intentionally is not meant to happen? as the reversal of e.g. , {{class1}} {{class2}} , which by this markup is defined, but ignored by either angular / domengine

Comment: I dont understand why the order of css class names matters. What css framework are you using?

Comment: You should be using ng-class for this type of thing. What does `ng-class="changesindividually"` do?

Comment: changesindividually as typeof placeholder of {{}} or the return of a function within the scope. it doesn't seem to make a difference tho

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to interact with the class-related property on an Element, you will note that the property (classList) is not a string, but a collection of strings. Treating it as a string can introduce various bugs that depend on the specific implementation of each environment (Chrome might do things differently than IE for example).

CSS itself doesn't care about the order of the classes, so i'm going to assume that the problem you have is in the way you manipulate the classes on the element. Consider using the [classList API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) which is not order-dependent and an overall saner version to achieve your goal.

You should also consider [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to set dynamic classes on an element and avoid fragile string manipulation.

```
<div ng-controller="controller2" ng-class="clsArray">

$scope.clsArray = ['one', 'column', 'wide'];
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but results in the following: (firebug) <div class="ng-scope wide column sixteen" ng-class="middleColumnsClass" ng-controller="mainCtrl"> where middleColumnsClass = ['sixteen','column','wide']

Comment: @F4b My answer was trying to convince you that you don't need to rely on the order of the classes.

Comment: Alright, it obviously doesn't seem to be a good idea doing it this way in angularJS. I expected it to handle this a bit more strict, but actually it could even be this is not angulars fault but happens in the process of pre-rendering. Thank you.